# Finding a general expression for a recursively defined sequence.

Tags: sequences-and-series, recurrence-relations, closed-form, pattern-recognition

I have a sequence of numbers that I would like to find a general expression for. The sequence is defined as follows.
$$C_m=\frac{1}{2m-3}\left[C_{m-1}+\frac{m^2-9m+16}{9\cdot 2^{m+4}(m-4)!}\right], m\geq 6$$
With the the seed being $C_5=-\frac{1}{5760}$.

The strategy would be to calculate several terms to try to find any patterns and then use induction to try to prove some general expression for $C_m$.
I have calculated - by hand - the first 7 terms with no promising pattern in sight.

$$C_5=-\frac{1}{2^7\cdot3^2\cdot5}$$
$$C_6=-\frac{13}{2^{10}\cdot3^4\cdot5}$$
$$C_7=-\frac{1}{2^{11}\cdot3^4\cdot5}$$
$$C_8=\frac{1}{2^{12}\cdot3^4\cdot5}$$
$$C_9=\frac{1}{2^{10}\cdot3^5\cdot5^2}$$
$$C_{10}=\frac{19}{2^{17}\cdot3^5\cdot5^2}$$
$$C_{11}=\frac{29}{2^{18}\cdot3^5\cdot5^2\cdot7}$$

It it also tempting to use the recursive definition to try to get a sum representation for $C_m$, but this just gets ugly really quick.

I should also explain why I have reason to think that a general expression exists. The sequence is one sequence of a family of sequences that are in some sense connected to each other. All the previous sequences have had a provable general expression so thats why I suspect this would be possible for this sequence as well.

Does anyone see any patterns in the given terms or have any other strategies that could work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to use Mathematica. Upon giving Mathematica the code

```
RSolve[{a[n] == 
   1/(2 n - 3) (a[n - 1] + (n^2 - 9 n + 16)/(9*2^(n + 4)*(n - 4)!)), 
  a[5] == -1/5760}, a[n], n]
```

It outputs (in plain mathematical language)
$$a_n=\frac{2^{-4-n}\left(5n^3-60n^2+199n-192\right)\Gamma\left(\frac{2n-1}{2}\right)}{405\sqrt{\pi}(n-3)!\prod_{k=1}^{n-1}\left(k-\frac{1}{2}\right)}$$

Comment: If you use `FullSimplify` on the result you get
$a_n = \frac{2^{-4-n}(64+5(n-9)n)}{405\Gamma(n-3)} $.

Comment: Fantastic! I just proved it by induction with the help of this. Sadly it seems like the complexity of the expressions for these sequences is increasing with no bound.